# DirectShow Compile issue

Tags: c++, windows, directshow

I am working with vs2010 on 64bit platform and Windows SDKv 7.1. I built the baseclasses for the 64 bit platform and configured it in my project.
but i am facing the following issue.I am trying to interface a logitech 910 HD camera.

```
1>LogitechC910Interface.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_VariantClear
1>LogitechC910Interface.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CoCreateInstance
1>LogitechC910Interface.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CoUninitialize
1>LogitechC910Interface.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_VariantInit
1>LogitechC910Interface.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CoInitializeEx
1>C:\PMD\windows\windows64bit\PMDSDK\examples\Release\simple.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to review project settings to make sure that linker uses respective `.LIB` to find its way to the unresolved symbols. For those you mentioned, you need `ole32.lib` and `oleaut32.lib`. Or add into source code (instead of project settings):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "oleaut32.lib")
```

Comment: @vevin: If this answer helped you solve your problem, you should accept it by clicking the outlined tick right below the vote buttons (and vote up if you can).